# Expansion effect in navbar

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I'm trying to make an expansion effect in my navbar using angular.

I need when I click in "mostrar informações" the content must ride up.

The problem is that the superior part of my footer is not following the effect.

I try something like:

```
<footer class="page-footer font-small footer-fundo-cinza">
   <div class="container">
      <div class="row pt-3">
         <div class="col-md-4">
            <img src="../../../assets/estilomotocar-rodape.png" class="img-responsive img-fluid">
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div [@fadeInUpDown]="mostrar_informacoes" [@statusDisplay]="mostrar_informacoes" class="row">
   <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-12">
            <hr>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</footer>
```

**My animations:**

```
export const statusDisplay =

    trigger('statusDisplay', [
        state('aberto',  style({ display: 'block' })),
        state('fechado', style({ display: 'none'  })),
        transition('fechado => aberto', animate('0ms ease')),
        transition('aberto => fechado', animate('0ms 200ms ease'))
    ])


export const fadeInUpDown =

    trigger('fadeInUpDown', [
        state('fechado', style({
            transform: 'translate3d(0,100%,0)'
        })),
        state('aberto', style({
            transform: 'translate3d(0,0,0)'
        })),
        transition('fechado <=> aberto', animate('400ms ease'))
    ])
```

If I put my animation direct in my footer the effect work but the translate3d make my nav go out the page, making a scroll.

My CSS:

```
 footer{
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 0;
   width: 100%;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not enough to evaluate your problem . Generally in Angular and any other web language you would need to explain your css very good . In that case I would propose a wrapper element :

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="ride-up">
<div class="ride-up-element"> Some text here </div>
</div>
 </div
```

And then the CSS  :

```
.wrapper {
display : flex ; 
flex-direction : row/column ; 
width : you choose it ;
height : as well : 
other-options : also you choose; 
}
.ride-up {
width : you choose it ;
height : as well : 
}
.ride-up:hover {
some css goes here ....
}
.ride-up-element {
some other css goes here....
}
```